# javascript canvas image onload drawImage not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, onload, undo, drawimage

I was trying to make a eraser with the canvas, and implement a undo, redo function by putting edited canvas images into an array using **jquery-3.4.1**. But it keeps on **showing an empty canvas** whenever I use the **clearrect** and **drawimage** function. I did try the **onload**, and change the **src** of the new image **after the onload**, but I couldn't fix it. Just change the **./fd.png** to run the code snippet.
I am quite the noob so I hope I didn't make any silly mistakes. 
Thx in advance.

```js
//showing save
var text1 = document.getElementById("1");
var text2 = document.getElementById("2");
var text3 = document.getElementById("3");
var text4 = document.getElementById("4");
var text5 = document.getElementById("5");
var text6 = document.getElementById("6");

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var savedataurl = [];
var currentsavedataline = 0;
var savelimit = 6;
var mousecheck = false;

base_image = new Image();
base_image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
//put starting image here
base_image.src = "./fd.png";

function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = 0,
    curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while ((obj = obj.offsetParent));
    return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
  }
  return undefined;
}

var timeout,
  clicker = $("#canvas"),
  x2,
  y2;

clicker.mousemove(function(e2) {
  var pos2 = findPos(this);
  x2 = e2.pageX - pos2.x;
  y2 = e2.pageY - pos2.y;
});

clicker.mousedown(function(e) {
  if (e.which != 1) return;

  savedataurl.length = currentsavedataline + 1;

  if (savedataurl.length < savelimit) {
    savedataurl[currentsavedataline] = canvas.toDataURL();
    currentsavedataline++;
  } else if (savedataurl.length == savelimit) {
    savedataurl.shift();
    savedataurl[currentsavedataline] = canvas.toDataURL();
  }
  //show saved pics
  text1.src = savedataurl[0];
  text2.src = savedataurl[1];
  text3.src = savedataurl[2];
  text4.src = savedataurl[3];
  text5.src = savedataurl[4];
  text6.src = savedataurl[5];

  mousecheck = true;
  var pos = findPos(this);
  var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
  var y = e.pageY - pos.y;

  context.strokeStyle = "#00000000";

  timeout = setInterval(function() {
    // Do something continuously
    context.beginPath();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    context.arc(x2, y2, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    context.save();
  }, 15);
  return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  clearInterval(timeout);
  if (mousecheck == false) return;
  if (e.which != 1) return;
  savedataurl[currentsavedataline] = canvas.toDataURL();
  mousecheck = false;
  return false;
});

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;

function KeyPress(e) {
  var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;

  function bringbackimg() {
    var backimg = new Image();
    backimg.onload = function() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(backimg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      img = backimg;
    };
    backimg.src = savedataurl[currentsavedataline];
  }
  // undo ctrl + z
  if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
    if (currentsavedataline > "0") {
      currentsavedataline--;
      bringbackimg();
    }
  }
  // redo ctrl + y
  if (evtobj.keyCode == 89 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
    if (currentsavedataline < savedataurl.length - 1) {
      currentsavedataline++;
      bringbackimg();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="./jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <br />
      <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      <div id="status">
        <p>1<img src="#" id="1" alt="" width="100" /></p>
        <p>2<img src="#" id="2" alt="" width="100" /></p>
        <p>3<img src="#" id="3" alt="" width="100" /></p>
        <p>4<img src="#" id="4" alt="" width="100" /></p>
        <p>5<img src="#" id="5" alt="" width="100" /></p>
        <p>6<img src="#" id="6" alt="" width="100" /></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you check for any error in dev console ?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found),GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/undefined 404 (Not Found) is shown but this is because of the var text1~6 I believe... It shows no errors when I press ctrl z and ctrl y...